# Why UITextfield setBackground UIColor White turn to transparent?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uicolor

I am writing an app and I want to make a textfield background turn white.

So far this is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UITextField *txtfield = UsernameTextField;
    [txtfield setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.5]  ];

    txtfield.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    txtfield.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    txtfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

But this code have a result like this:

[image: error]

and i tried this code , to increast alpha

```
[txtfield setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.8]  ];
```

still the same

and also i see this post

[iPhone UITextField background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971598/iphone-uitextfield-controlling-background-color)

and i tried

[image]

but it still the same

Why textfield wont turn to white?

Comment: You're setting a 0.5 alpha. Try changing it to something closer to 1.

Comment: i changed to 0.8 but still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first you should

- `[super viewDidLoad]` should be the first statement in `- (void)viewDidLoad` after initialising parent child should do initialise.

Second

- Please check the order of views put on view controller bring `UsernameTextField` to top of all views or you can call `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:txtfield]` in code

Third

- Only by setting alpha to 1.0 you can see complete white background.

and finally is you still don't get it resolved then there is some changes you did in xib/storyboard view. So to reset just delete textfield and add it again.

Comment: it  works! thanks!, i delete the text field and i add again and now the uitextfield is now white, this is so confusing .thanks million, how the heck this can be happen

Answer (score 1):

In order to change background color it's important to set the border to None

```
txtfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

**Details**: [Changing background colour within a TextField in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155579/changing-background-colour-within-a-textfield-in-interface-builder)

[iPhone UITextField background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971598/iphone-uitextfield-controlling-background-color)

From Apple Doc:

> When set, the image referred to by this property replaces the standard appearance controlled by the borderStyle property. Background images are drawn in the border rectangle portion of the text field. Images you use for the text field’s background should be able to stretch to fit.

Comment: i dont know why, other people successed, i tried those articles but still not working

Comment: Try to comment out the `masksToBound` statement